# Backbone.js with jQuery draggable / droppable. Droppable isn't working

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone app where I am creating 2 views, one draggable, and one droppable. Dragging works ok, but the droppable callback is never fired. How can I get the droppable view to "see" the draggable one?

My "droppable" view:

```
class App.Views.Folder extends Backbone.View

template: JST['folders/folder']

  className: "folder"

  initialize: (options) ->
    @collection.on('add', @addOne, @)
    @collection.on('reset', @addAll, @)

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
   this.$el.droppable(
      drop: -> alert("dropped!")
   );
```

Draggable:

```
class App.Views.QuestionSet extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['question_sets/question_set']

  className: "question-set"

  initialize: (options) ->
    @collection.on('add', @addOne, @)
    @collection.on('reset', @addAll, @)
    @$el.draggable(
      handle: ".drag-question-set"
      revert: true
    )

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
```

### Update:

The droppable elements fire the callback correctly when I insert the `$(draggable.el)` into the same container dive as the droppable view. It just doesn't like it when they are in separate html parents...

Comment: What do your templates look like and how are you inserting these views into the page?

Comment: @muistooshort Just placeholder eco templates at this point.. I'm inserting the elements via the router when the index action is hit.
`$('#folders').html(folders_view.render().el)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... Turns out it was a "tolerance" issue with the Droppable plugin. Setting `{tolerance: "pointer"}` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's not too much information in your post, but based on your description, if it depends on where in html you put your droppable, you could try replacing your `@$el` references with just `$("#someid")` instead. Also, remember that with backbone, the shortcut `@$("#someid")` is scoped to the backbone view element (some sub element of the global document set in the constructor), not the global document itself. Assuming you get the `$("#someid")` parts to work, it's most probably just a scoping issue.

Comment: This is what I thought too. It turns out it was an issue with the droppable in a div with `float: left`. I am using Bootstrap and the container div has a `span3` class.. As soon as I remove that class, it works fine.. So, not a Backbone or CoffeeScript issue, but some kind of weird CSS / jQuery bug. Any thoughts here? Thanks for your help.